# Display "numpages" in bibliography with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I don't have page numbers for a paper and would like to add "numpages" instead so they render in by PDF. I am using `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`. Is there somewhere I can specify the use of "numpages" for only bibentries which don't have the pages specified?

```
\begin{filecontents}{shortbib.bib}
@inproceedings{supercurve,
     AUTHOR={Santara Xia},
     TITLE={Image Registration by "Super-Curves"},
     booktitle={IEEE Transactions on Image Processing},
     YEAR={2000},
     numpages = {10}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}

\title{A Silly Article}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
My favorite article is \cite{supercurve}.
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{shortbib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about adding this information as `note`? If you want to introduce new fields, biblatex would be much easier to customise.

```
\begin{filecontents}{shortbib.bib}
@inproceedings{supercurve,
     AUTHOR={Santara Xia},
     TITLE={Image Registration by "Super-Curves"},
     booktitle={IEEE Transactions on Image Processing},
     YEAR={2000},
     note = {10 pages}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}

\title{A Silly Article}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
My favorite article is \cite{supercurve}.
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{shortbib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Do you know the note can be customised where in the bibliography it appears? Right now it presents the page numbers at the end (after the year). Do you know if it would be possible to add it before the year?

Comment: @Jo- I really suggest to switch to biblatex. With biblatex it is easy to reorder fields, but in bibtex it is a pain in the a**